# How can 4 limbed animals evolve from 6 limbed animals?

Tags: science-based, creature-design, evolution, mythical-creatures, fantasy-races

An idea that I've been having to logically explain the evolution of 6-limbed animals is that they naturally have a common ancestor. This is illustrated in this picture I found:

[image]

Source: *Birvan* from DeviantArt

This is a great way to explain the evolution of Dragons, Centaurs, and Angels. However, I've been wondering if over time, animals could lose their limbs to become the animals we know today? For example, could there be a world where normal humans evolved from an ancestor with 6 limbs, or a Sleipnir species living alongside normal horses?